# Maven set environment variable inside pom.xml

Tags: maven

I'm trying to set a environment variable inside `pom.xml`. I was doing something like this with `maven-surefire-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
    <environmentVariables>
      <MY_PATH>${project.parent.relativePath}</MY_PATH>
    </environmentVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But i can't access it from another `pom.xml` with `${env.MY_MATH}`. I can only access it with `System.getenv("MY_PATH")` inside JAVA. I need to access it in another `pom.xml`. Maybe there are some other plugins that are doing that? I know that i can pass it with `mvn -DMY_PATH=some/path install` but it will just set it inside the pom where i passed this var and i need it to be setted as global env.

Comment: Why do you need an environment variable within your build (in another pom)?

Comment: For what purpose? Which kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What kind of plugin? A plugin that needs an environment variable sounds wrong... please can you give much more details...

Comment: here is the plugin: https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-vuejs . What i'm trying to do is not standard thing thtat's why i was asking the question here on stackoverflow. I'm acessing the path in `webpack.config.js`. But thats other question.

Comment: Hm... sorry does not really help to understand the problem.. because env variables are usually only used in application.properties to define credentials but it it does not make sense to transfer credentials during build time? And what kind of path is needed?

Comment: @khmarbaise but in `webpack.config.js` i can access the environment variable with `process.env.PATH` and what i'm trying to do is to access the setted var from `pom.xml`. Is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do. Are you trying to set variables for runtime? That will not be possible because Maven is a build tool.